# Is a pilegesh the same as a handmaiden?

Tags: halacha, marriage, slave-serve-eved-avadim

I'm confused as to whether what the actual relationship to a man a pilegesh actually has in Jewish Law.  I've seen conflicting sources:   (1) Hebrew school taught a pilegesh is a secondary wife (concubine) who the man marries separately since his first wife cannot have a child and so the contract is between the man and said secondary wife; or (2) Genesis teaches a pilegesh is a servant (handmaiden) contracted by the primary wife to offer to the man when she herself cannot have a child, and the the relationship is actually between the primary wife and her handmaiden, with the servant standing in as the primary's surrogate.  Please clarify?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/search?q=title:pilegesh+is:question

Comment: Citing precise sources as opposed to a vague " I've seen conflicting sources:" may improve the quality of this question.

Comment: I'm not a Torah scholar.  I'm asking Torah scholars.

Comment: By handmaiden, do you mean *shipheḥah* (שפחה)?